# can't run scala

Tags: java, 15.04

```
kdtrey@durantstat:~$ scala
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45-internal).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> [init] error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 76)
```

Is there a workaround for this? I tried reinstalling openJDK but that didn't work at all either.

Answer (score 4):

Scala 2.9.2 doesn't work well with Java 8, so either upgrade Scala or downgrade Java. [Here's a near duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517761/scala-repl-throws-error).